# mysql root password is unable to change in fedora

Tags: mysql, passwords, fedora

Since mysql root password is empty by default, I decided to create a password for it for the security of my mysql database. I tried to change the root password using this command:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

after trying to renewing the it's password it gave me this warning and error:

> Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
>   mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements'

what should I do with this?

please click the image link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you can't set the password you've chosen because it is not strong enough to match the policy requirements. The policy level is configured with the system variable `validate_password_policy`, which hase the following effect:

```
0 or LOW    Length
1 or MEDIUM Length; numeric, lowercase/uppercase, and special characters
2 or STRONG Length; numeric, lowercase/uppercase, and special characters; dictionary file
```

(and the length test is the value of `validate_password_length`.)

Looks like the default is level is MEDIUM and the default length is 8, so you need a mixed-case password with at least a number and a special character.

So, either:

1. Reduce the strength of the tests in your configuration, or
2. Choose a stronger password (recommended).